# Entity Relationship diagram interpretations of a inventory database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

This is a Entity relationship diagram of Inventory database.
[image: ER Diagram]
How we can interpret it? my idea is like there is list of `product` with Dealer, customer `orders` the product. `supplier` supplies it. customer `purchases` it. But i think i'm not able to perfectly interpret it. what does the above ER diagram shows.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diagram says that "products" are "purchased" from "suppliers" and "ordered" by customers (which are only named in the orders table and do not have a separate entity).